# How to limit datetime UI to select only dates after today or now?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

i understand that there are lots of solution for datetimepicker, but im using a textbox in asp.net which textmode is Date, so i want to make sure that it only shows dates that is today or after.How can i do it?

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
<asp:TextBox ID="endDateTb" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="EndDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Also, if the textbox date is past today's date (example, endDate = 2th Jan 2019, and now is 3th jan 2019), i would like the database to automatically call the delete query from database.
Any idea how can i do it

Comment: Please only add relevant tags :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Attributes` property with HTML `min` attribute in code-behind to specify minimum date since the textbox will render as `<input type="date">`:

```
endDateTb.Attributes["min"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Note that `min` attribute must be specified in `yyyy-MM-dd` format, otherwise it will be treated as no minimum value.

Second, regarding the date comparison, you could use simple if-condition to execute delete query:

```
// example to convert text box value to 'DateTime' instance
// if you have specific format, better to use DateTime.ParseExact or DateTime.TryParseExact
DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDateTb.Value); // or endDateTb.Text property

// compare both dates
if (DateTime.Today > endDate)
{
    // execute delete query here
}
```

Reference:

[HTML date input (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: as for the question regarding delete query, can i know if it checks from database? because i need to do it on page_load and if enddate is up, it will not show any data from that column.

Comment: The second problem depends on what kind of data with certain keys you want to delete, but you're not specified about that here so I just gave the condition to check both dates. You can use SELECT query to find out matched data and delete them afterwards.